# Convergence of Schrödinger ground states in $L^p$ for $p\neq 2$

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, operator-theory, schrodinger-operators

Suppose that $H=-\Delta+V$ is a Schrödinger operator with a unique ground state $\psi$. Suppose that $H_n=-\Delta+V_n$ is a sequence of operators such that $V_n\to V$ in some sense as $n\to\infty$ (more on this in a bit), also with a unique ground state $\psi_n$. I am interested in the following type of problem:

> **Question.** Are there known sufficient conditions on the convergence of the potentials $V_n\to V$ that guarantee the convergence of ground states $\|\psi_n-\psi\|_{L^p}$ in some $L^p$ norm?

Here, I am especially interested in the convergence in $L^p$ for $p\neq 2$. I can find some pretty strong results in the $L^2$ setting; e.g., in [this paper](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1023/A:1008654423238), for one dimension, weak convergence $\langle f,V_n\rangle\to\langle f,V\rangle$ for every bounded and continuous $f$ implies norm-resolvent convergence of the operators $H_n$ to $H$ in $L^2$. That being said, I found no result for other values of $1\leq p\leq \infty$.

Comment: Could you concretise the problem a bit? On what kind of domain are you working, and with what hypotheses on $V_n,V$?

Comment: @LeoMoos I'm interested in the case where $H$ and $H_n$ are defined on all of $\mathbb R^d$. For the specific application that I have in mind, $V$ and $V_n$ happen to be continuous functions with exponential decay, so in $L^p$ for all $1\leq p\leq \infty$.

Comment: I don't think a general ground state will even be in $L^p$ for $p<2$.

Comment: @ChristianRemling I should have also mentioned, I'm mostly interested in the case where the potential is strictly negative, in which case I believe the ground states can be shown to have exponential decay.

Comment: @user78370: Are you sure about this? Can't I (in one dimension) just start out with a $y(x)>0$, $y\in L^2$ (say $y(x)=(1+x^2)^{-\alpha}$) and then define $V(x)=E+y''(x)/y(x)$, with suitable $E<0$. Then $E$ will be an eigenvalue because $y$ solves $-y''+Vy=Ey$, and $V$ should be negative if $E$ was small enough. Moreover, $E$ is the ground state by oscillation theory ($y$ doesn't have zeros).

Comment: @ChristianRemling Thank you for your example. I vaguely remember some results about ground states when $V$ is in the Kato class etc., but your comment (as well as Leo's) seems to indicate that I would benefit from framing a more precise question in terms of assumptions on $V_n$ and $V$.